# how to insert the image tag into hyperlink tag at dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have these tags

```
 img = <img data-dz-thumbnail="" target="_blank" alt="twitter-btn-mob.png" src="image.jpg">
 a = <a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank"></a>
```

now i want to insert the image tag into a tag 
 for this i did

```
 a.innerHTML = img
```

then its given like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">[object Object]</a>
```

but its wrong. Please help me

Comment: Sound like syntax is missing. var img = "<img data-dz-thumbnail='' target='_blank' alt='twitter-btn-mob.png' src='image.jpg'>"; var a = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' target='_blank'></a>"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a').html('<img data-dz-thumbnail="" target="_blank" alt="twitter-btn-mob.png" src="image.jpg">');
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/ba8eqa0v/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">'+img+'</a>');
```

Comment: While your answer may be the perfect solution for the OP, we on SO would definitely like to read explanation about the parts of your answer that helped resolve the problem. Let me know when you edit the answer.

Comment: it's simple answer `concatination in javascript` ,so what should i write in explanation.